# TYPO3 7 PlugIn without a Model and/or Repository

Tags: typo3, extbase

following situation: I will write a PlugIn that shows only content throw a extern API (i need a controller to execute my calls). And i can´t add this plugin via typoscript shown in this tutorial (in german): https://advitum.de/2013/05/einstieg-in-extbase-ein-plugin-ohne-models/. So i don´t need a full MVC Model but my solution wan´t work.

The whole proplem is i have no output in the frontend. The controller is never called.

Can everyone tell me how can i do this?

Ok I have to give to my question more information.

this is my ext_table.php:

```
if(!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) die('Access denied.');

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'MB.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'MBTest',
    'Show Test'
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY, 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'MBTest');
```

my ext_localconf.php:

```
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die('Access denied.');
}

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'MB.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'MBTest',
    array(
        'Static' => 'statistic', 
    ),
);
```

my Controller:

```
namespace MB\Mbtest\Controller;

class StaticController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{
    /**
     * action statistic
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function statisticAction()
    {
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extabse\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump('hello');
        $this->view->assign('testLIST', 'MBTest say Hello');
    }
}
```

and i have also the standard typoscript files for the templates. 
My template (Statistic.html looks like this:

```
<f:layout name="Default" />
<f:section name="main">
<f:flashMessages />
<h1>Test</h1> 
{listTEST} 
</f:section>
```

[EDIT]
Is there a another way to make call´s to my API via php and show the computed result in my template?

Comment: Ok, downvoted why?

Comment: What exactly does not work, can you elaborate a bit, maybe show some code? You don't need a model to have controllers, controllers just have built in support to make working with models easier.

Comment: Your solution does not work. OK. So, what does your solution look like?

Comment: OK thx. i will edit my question

Comment: I have no output in the frontend...

Comment: You say you have no output. Can you tell the controller is called? How does your Resources/Private/Templates/Static/Statistic.html looks like?

Comment: so here is my template (Statistic.html):

`<f:layout name="Default" />

<f:section name="main">
<h1>Test</h1>

<f:flashMessages />

{listTEST}

</f:section>`

Comment: did you clear install tool cache or disable and enable your extension from extension manager

Comment: Caching is disable in my extension and for the page to.

Comment: Does your layout contain `<f:render section="main"/>`?

Comment: #Jost if there problem in view/layout then must be he get view render error but he faced problem with controller is never called. what should be there? TCA or ext_localconf.php non-cacheable actions?

Comment: @GhanshyamGohel The cached action should not prevent the content from the template to be rendered - the content would be cached, at least the headline should show up. But you are right, the cached action would later prevent any API calls from being made.

Comment: Did you add your plugin to a page?

Comment: Ok the extension efempty from the TYPO3-TER is not very usefull for. The only diiferent to my extension is that i have no model. But this extension wan´t work in TYPO 7.6 .https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/efempty

Comment: I have tested and efempty extension works well with v7.6x http://screencast.com/t/mQznICD4 did you add FE plugin in your page? http://screencast.com/t/Ck6FNWboxO2b

Answer (score 2):

Dude. Check your spellings. You're assigning

```
$this->view->assign('testLIST', 'MBTest say Hello');
```

but then you want your template to render

```
{listTEST}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first code sample is from 'ext_table.php'. Could it be a simple misspelling of 'ext_tables.php'?